# Webdav troubleshooting: OSX to NextCloudPi

Tags: macos, webdav

NCP Webdav functionality was verified from an Ubuntu device.  From the OSX command line terminal:

```
mount_webdav -i https://fqdn.duckdns.org/remote.php/webdav/ /Users/user/ncp
```

points to a nextcloudPi server and did not return anything (except a prompt for the username + password).

Test 1:

```
ls /Users/user/ncp
```

returned nothing.

Test 2:

```
 mount | grep Users/user/ncp
```

returned nothing.

Questions:

1. Where to begin troubleshooting?
2. What does success look like upon issuing the `mount_webdav` command?
3. Should test 2 be expected to return anything?

Any diagnostic test questions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might have more luck with my tool ocsmount.

It can mount a Nextcloud server that will show up in your file system.

https://ocsmount.com/macos-webdav-mount.html